How to send Mails in the Same thread using Microsoft Graph API
I am trying to send Mail using Microsoft Graph API in the same thread .
I have tried using the /messages/{message_ID}/reply endpoint which sends the mail in the same thread , but if the subject changes then it doesn't send the mail in the same thread .
I have tried creating the draft and then update the subject still its not working also.
There isn't any way to add headers to add the References and In-Reply-To so that it follows in the same thread , I can add only the internetMessageHeaders which takes the headers as X-{headers-name}
I just want to send mail in the same thread even if the subject changes in Micorsoft Graph API in Node and Express
